# How to reset my collection on load and later to go just update

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

In my Backbone function, i am fetching the data from server as first time.(it has bunch of datas) and i am adding to document. According to the client requirement i should keep watch the server every 10sec, and need to apply the elements to the document. I am always using the "reset" call back to render the elements..

But i need to apply all the element to document as firt time, later part just it is enough to update, how can i do like..?

here is a partial stuff from my code:

```
initialize:function(params){
            _.bindAll(this);
            var that = this;
            this.listItems = ["projectName","assignedTo","projectName"];
            this.classItems = ["projectName","assignedTo","sortBy"];
            this.listCatch = [];this.boardCatch=[];
            this.params = params;

            for(var i=0;i<this.listItems.length; i+=1){
                this.listCatch[i] = [];
            }

            this.collection = new singleton.collection;
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render);
                    //on load resetting..           
            var dataFetcher = function(){
                that.collection.fetch();
                appDataFetcher = setTimeout(dataFetcher,10000);
                    // as well all times resetting the whole data...
            };
            var appDataFetcher = setTimeout(dataFetcher,0); 
        },
        render:function(){
            this.listCollection = this.collection;
            this.boardCollection = this.collection;
            this.listCollect();
            this.boardViewSet();
        },
        listCollect:function(){
            var that = this;
            _(this.listItems).forEach(function(key,i){
                var uniqur = _.uniq(that.listCollection.models, function(item){
                    return item.get(key);
                });
                that.listViewSet(key,i,uniqur);
            });
        },
```

Comment: try using `that.collection.fetch({update: true, remove: false});`

Comment: Nothing happening.. no data loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set my fetching process like this.. it works fine as like i expected. But if this is not correct approach let any one correct me..?

```
this.collection.on('add', this.render); 
this.collection.on('remove', this.render);  
        var dataFetcher = function(){
            that.collection.fetch({update:true,remove:true});
            appDataFetcher = setTimeout(dataFetcher,10000);
        };
 var appDataFetcher = setTimeout(dataFetcher,0);
```